# Order of git operations

Tags: git, github

I am trying to get my head around the order of git operations for getting a code change from my local repo to GitHub. Below is my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong:

1. Clone repo from GitHub (at this point my GitHub repo only has a master branch).
2. Create a new branch locally.
3. Make changes on the new branch and commit.
4. Push the new branch changes to GitHub using git push.

   Question: Does a new branch now get created on GitHub? Does `git push` need any additional arguments?
5. Create a pull request on GitHub.
6. Merge my new branch into the master branch on GitHub.

   Question: Do I now merge new branch into master branch locally?
7. Delete local new branch.

Comment: 4. Yes, and it tells you what to do when you try to push without them. 6. No. I'd recommend running through e.g. https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Answer (score 1):

### Question: Does a new branch now get created on GitHub? Does git push need any additional arguments?

When you push the branch it will try to push the changes to the default remote (in your case GitHub), whether you need to add any arguments depends. You can explicitly tell it to push to a specific branch or to push to a new branch with a specific name. When you omit everything git will ask you to set the "upstream", the branch name on the remote:

```
>git checkout -B new
Switched to a new branch 'new'

>git push
fatal: The current branch new has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin new
```

That way you only have to set the upstream once and from then on you can use `git push` without arguments. Instead you can explicitly push to a branch as well:

```
>git push origin new
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'new' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/jessehouwing/test/pull/new/new
remote:
To https://github.com/jessehouwing/test.git
 * [new branch]      new -> new
```

But this won't set the upstream branch and will require you to tell which remote branch to push to every time you perform `git push`. Hence, it makes sence to set the upstream in most cases.

### Question: Do I now merge new branch into master branch locally?

My recommendation would be to fetch the changes first:

```
>git fetch origin master
From https://github.com/jessehouwing/test
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Now the And then create a new branch for your next set of changes

```
git checkout origin/master -B second-new-branch --no-track
```

That way you never even have a local copy of `master` and will always work from a branch created for your specific purpose. It also helps you to not make changes on the wrong branch. I've added `--no-track` so the branch won't be linked to `origin/master` upon pushing, allowing you to make a new pull request.

This way you won't ever to resolve merge conflicts into master locally and can always create new branches from the latest state of the remote repo.

Comment: I highly recommend you run through a bunch of Git/GitHub tutorials, it will help you get a better grasp of all of the steps involved: https://lab.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, **pull requests are not a git feature.** They are directly opposed to the nature and spirit and technical underpinnings of git. They are a feature provided by github to enable controlled cooperative collaboration and communication. Don’t use them unless you have to because **your code must be reviewed by someone else** along with the resulting conversation.

If you *do* have to use pull requests, then the steps you outlined are basically correct, except they omit the actual review by someone else. Here's an actual workflow taken from real life, rephrasing yours:

1. Clone repo from GitHub [once].
2. Create a new branch locally.
3. Make changes and add-and-commit.
4. Push the branch to GitHub.
5. Create a pull request on GitHub, asking to merge that branch into master. Ask for review.

   1. Discussion of the code.
   2. If needed, make more changes locally (still on the same branch) and add-and-commit and push; the changes become part of the same pull request automatically. Repeat these two sub-steps as necessary.
6. When the pull request is approved, merge the branch into master on GitHub. When GitHub offers to let you delete the branch, do so.
7. Back on your machine, switch to master and pull.
8. Delete the branch.
9. Start again at 2.

If there is **no collaborator or code review** then your steps would be completely wrong; in that case all merging would take place locally and you would never visit github at all.

Comment: Or if you have a CI system hooked up and want to keep your `master` branch clean :).

Comment: @jessehouwing That's a very fair point, thanks! Of course a lot depends on how the CI system is set up.